# Web Service to save the received string array list from android to a file

Tags: c#, web-services, arraylist

I am very new to web services.

How to putup a web service(asmx) which can receive a String array list and save the received list to a text file(or an XML file)

Comment: [WebMethod]
    public List<string> GetStringList()
    {
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    return list;
    }
I couldn't proceed any further, I am not sure weather the web method is correct or not

Comment: Please add the current code (and the problem/exception you have/get) to the question...

Comment: I have no idea how to save the arraylist to a file. I am searching for a probable soultion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving an array to file - what do you exactly mean? 
Do you want to save it to a file in a human readable way?

```
public void SaveDataToFile(string[] array)
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\temp\file.txt", true))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(array.Join(",", array); //save it as a comma separated list
    }
}
```

I think this method should do it in that case(add necessary webservice attributes, etc).